# Determine if sessions are enabled on an Azure Service Bus Queue

Tags: c#, azure-servicebus-queues

Is there a way in C# to programmatically determine if sessions are enabled on an Azure ServiceBus Queue?  I am using the Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.  I can see the older version has a way of determining, but I've not discovered it in this version.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly do that. The namespace you would want to use is [`Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Administration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.administration?view=azure-dotnet). The information you are looking for will be available in [`QueueProperties.RequiresSession`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.administration.queueproperties.requiressession?view=azure-dotnet#azure-messaging-servicebus-administration-queueproperties-requiressession) property in [`QueueProperties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.administration.queueproperties?view=azure-dotnet) class.